# How to wrap HTML to If Expression statements in Nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

Based on the following [docs,](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#if-expression) I can easily make use of the If Expressions as exampled.
But how can we take them further by wrapping HTML to the object?  I want to do something like this...

```json
{{ "<li>" . foo . "</li>" if foo else '' }}
```

what would be the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have recently discovered, one way to go about this process is to use the Join and Safe filters to help achieve this goal.  The following works for me today.

```cv
  {% set desc = ["<li class='m-y-sm'>", event.description, "</li>" ] | join | safe %}

  <ul>
    <li><p>guaranteed content</p></li>
    {{ desc if event.description else ''}}
  </ul>
```